# Response Content not Hydrating Object

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, dotnet-httpclient

I'm calling an API in the Controller of a MVC Core app as follows:

```
HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(string.Empty, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain");
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("api/users", httpContent);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
    User userJson = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<User>();                
    string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

The value of responseContent is:

```
"{
   \"actionName\":\"GetUser\",
   \"routeValues\":{\"id\":\"30131055-9ff0-472f-a147-69e76f7aac77\"},
   \"value\":{\"uid\":\"a36065bd-9d88-4ea3-f04d-08d98cfa8b83\",
   \"email\":\"example@example.org\",
   \"active\":true,\"created\":\"2021-10-12T19:49:16.0054897Z\",
   \"updated\":\"2021-10-12T19:49:16.0054899Z\"},\"formatters\":[],
   \"contentTypes\":[],
   \"statusCode\":201
}"
```

I wasn't expecting this type of formatted content, I was expecting JSON, but I can see my the values for my User object in the "value" section.

My User object properties of uid, email, active, created, and updated are all public properties with get/set methods.

So I can see that my data is there, but when I try to deserialize the response to the User object I just see the default values after instantiation.

I feel like I'm missing something simple.

Comment: Simply put: reading twice the response content is wrong and can fail depending on how the API you are using works. If you need to do this, first read as string and then deserialize from the already in-memory string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Christian Franco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11453973/cristian-franco) noticed that the items in the object being return matched [CreatedAtActionResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.createdatactionresult?view=aspnetcore-5.0) which the API I was calling was returning instead of the values I expected.  This explains the odd behavior I was seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Your User class appears not to match the response json, you can either create the class structure that matches the response like this

```
public class RouteValues
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class Value //your user class
{
    public string uid { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public bool active { get; set; }
    public DateTime created { get; set; }
    public DateTime updated { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public string actionName { get; set; }
    public RouteValues routeValues { get; set; }
    public Value value { get; set; }
    public List<object> formatters { get; set; }
    public List<object> contentTypes { get; set; }
    public int statusCode { get; set; }
}
```

and deserialize to the Response class and access the value object which is the equivalent to your user object or deserialize by specifying the key which does contain your user object, that being the value key.

Comment: Interesting, is this some kind of common .NET MVC response object that can be processed with some existing tool?

The API I'm calling just returns the user values - so it seems like the RouteValues, Value, and Response are being wrapped around it by something before the JSON data is returned.

Comment: I see, I think that it could be that the api is returning something like a  CreatedAtActionResult, that wraps your user data with other properties. Look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.createdatactionresult?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Thanks Cristian, the API was returning a CreatedAtActionResult instead of the values I was expecting.  I should be able to correct this so it returns the values instead.